# Call two chained independent methods using Rx

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have two async methods, that got to be called while one operation. Each method could be completed successfully or retrieve with error. On case of error, I got to retry call each method once again, with delayed of 2 sec. Mean, I should call both methods, despite of result of one of them. In error callback I want to know in which method error occured, or in both methods.

It seems I should use `Completable` for this, but I'm absolutely newbie in Rx.

```
private void method1(final CompletableEmitter e, String path){
Database.getInstance().getReference(path).addListener(new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(Data data) {
               //todo something
               e.onComplete();                
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
               e.onError(new Throwable(databaseError.getMessage()));
            }
        });
}
```

Method2 is the same. 
The following code doesn't work properly.

```
    Completable completable1 = Completable.create(method1(e););
    Completable completable2 = Completable.create(method2(e););

    completable1
            .doOnError(…)
            .retry(1)
            .andThen(completable2 //never called if completable1 gets onError each time
                    .retry(1)
                    .doOnError(…))
            .subscribe(…).dispose();
```

Comment: You might want to try finding an Rx wrapper for Firebase

Comment: @cricket_007 please don't focus on Firebase (edited)

Comment: Why not? It'll help you chain those methods that are apparently using Firebase

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of ways to do this. I'm going just to limit to explain how to achieve this using two `Completable`s

Let's say you have two completables:

```
Completable doSomething = ...
Completable doSomethingElse = ...
```

To execute these sequentially,
you can concatenate them using `andThen` operator. Then to delay a retry when an error occurs, you can use `retryWhen`:

```
doSomething.andThen(doSomethingElse)
    .retryWhen { Flowable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
    .subscribe()
```

This snippet above will retry infinitely if an error is permanently occurring. To go beyond, you can limit the number of tries using:

```
.retryWhen { errors ->
    val retryCounter = AtomicInteger()
    errors.flatMap {
        if (retryCounter.getAndIncrement() <= 3)
            Flowable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        else Flowable.error(it)
    }
}
```

If you want to retry only when a given type of error occurs, you can use:

```
.retryWhen { errors ->
    val retryCounter = AtomicInteger()
    errors.flatMap {
        if (it is YourSpecficError && retryCounter.getAndIncrement() <= 3)
            Flowable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        else Flowable.error(it)
    }
}
```

---

In the case you want to retry each one independently, you can use:

```
doSomething.retryWhen { ... }
    .andThen(doSomethingElse.retryWhen { ... })
    .subscribe()
```

In addition, in order to avoid the retryWhen logic duplication, you could encapsulate this in an extension function:

```
fun Completable.retryDelayed(): Completable {
    return this.retryWhen { errors ->
        val retryCounter = AtomicInteger()
        errors.flatMap {
            if (it is YourSpecficError && retryCounter.getAndIncrement() <= 3)
                Flowable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            else Flowable.error(it)
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to run your completables in parallel you ca use `merge` operator:

```
Completable doAll = Completable.merge(listOf(doSomething, doSomething))
```

Comment: What happens when `retry` called: both `completable` runs again? I need retry only one of them, in which error has been occured.

Comment: I added some more explanation to my answer

Comment: Are you sure `retryCounter` will not initializing to 0 each time?

Comment: Seems this doesn't work, `doSomethingElse` never called: doSomething.retryWhen { }.andThen(doSomethingElse.retryWhen { ... }).subscribe()

Comment: Try to get into the doc, there is a lot of operator and could be struggle in the first but the best way to start is trying/failing. Look and play with http://rxmarbles.com/ also. good luck